# Securing a plugin pop-up window

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, security

I have a plugin that opens a pop-up window and displays it's content in there, not using any of the default wordpress theme/style etc.

My question is, what is the best way of securing access to this window? At the moment if a user copies/pastes the address into the browser it will show the content. I would like it to only be visible to users logged in with the role of admin.

Yet when i add some basic security to the plugin landing page, it affects the entire site, not just the plugin page:

```
my-plugin.php (located in /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin)

function check_logged_in() {
    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        die('foo');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'check_logged_in' );
```

This is being executed whether i am visiting the plugin page, or any other page on the site. I would like it to apply only to the plugin / subdirectories from the plugin (i.e. will apply to mysite.com/plugin/view-orders but not on mysite.com/contact)

Comment: for security you don't want the popup contents to be directly accessible. set the popup address to `admin-ajax.php` and add an AJAX action that does the security check that if passed includes the PHP file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - could you explain what you mean with a code example?

Comment: ok see posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add some AJAX actions in your plugin file, something like this... The first one (without `_nopriv`) will already only be executed for logged in users, and the second will only be executed for logged out users, so there is no need to retest `is_user_logged_in()` here:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_show_popup_contents', 'show_popup_contents');
function show_popup_contents() {
    $filepath = dirname(__FILE__).'/popup.php';
    include($filepath); exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_show_popup_contents', 'deny_popup_contents');
function deny_popup_contents() {
    wp_die("You need to be logged in to view these contents.");
}
```

Then set the popup URL to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=show_popup_contents`

You probably want to also add `if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {exit;}` at the top of the included `popup.php` file so it cannot be accessed directly that way.